# Find for how many values of $n$. $I_n=\int_0^1 \frac {1}{(1+x^2)^n} \, dx = \frac 14 + \frac {\pi}8$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find for how many values of $n$. $I_n=\int_0^1 \frac {1}{(1+x^2)^n} \, dx=\frac 14 + \frac {\pi}8$

My attempt (integration by parts):

\begin{align}
I_n & = \int_0^1 \frac 1{(1+x^2)^n}\,dx = \left. \frac {x}{(1+x^2)^n} \right|_0^1+2n\int_0^1 \frac {x^2+1-1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}\,dx \\[10pt]
& =\frac 1{2^n}+2n \times I_n-2n\times I_{n+1}\implies I_{n+1}= \frac 1{2^{n+1}n}+\frac {2n-1}{2n}I_n.
\end{align}

where $I_1=\frac {\pi}{4}.$

Finding out that $I_2=\frac {\pi}{8}+\frac 14.$ But how do I find out that this is the *only* solution?

Comment: Given your method, you only need note that $I_{n+1}<I_n$ with your conditions to show that the integral will never equal $\frac\pi8 +\frac14$ again.

Comment: This is the first time I've ever seen someone write \mbox{ } and then put the one narrow symbol inside the {curly braces} between dollar signs (since it's mathematical notation). The purpose of using \mbox{} could not have been to prevent a line break in such a situation, nor was it used instead of \text{}. At any rate I did some formatting in various parts of this question and that is no longer there.

Comment: Calculator computation gives a different value for $I_3$ than your recurrence though. Calculator says $I_3\approx 0.5445243113$, but recurrence gives $I_3\approx0.5564159014$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yeaaaah, sorry for that, but I don't know how to use that thing tho :-?? So i had to "improve" something

Comment: May I ask from which book did you get this question from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The sequence $I_n$ is strictly decreasing because for $x\in (0,1]$,
$$0<\frac {1}{1+x^2} <1.$$
.

Comment: Yep I did that later. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Note that the sequence $(I_n)$ is decreasing, hence there is at most one value of $n$ such that $I_n=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\pi}{8}$.